# Get Base64 encoded GZipped String from RabbitMQ with Java

Tags: java, arrays, rabbitmq, base64, gzip

I've implemented some GzipUtil which works pretty good and looks like this:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.exceptions.Base64DecodingException;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class GzipUtil {
    public static void unzip(String putBase64EncodedGzippedStringHere) throws Base64DecodingException {
        byte[] compressed = Base64.decode(putBase64EncodedGzippedStringHere);

        if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot unzip null or empty bytes");
        }
        if (!isZipped(compressed)) {
            System.out.println(compressed);
        }

        try (ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed)) {
            try (GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
                try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader =
                             new InputStreamReader(gzipInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
                        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            output.append(line);
                            System.out.println(output.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to unzip content", e);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isZipped(final byte[] compressed) {
        return (compressed[0] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC))
                && (compressed[1] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC >> 8));
    }
}
```

Now I've got some other code that consumes a RabbitMQ queue like this:

```
ConnectionFactory rabbitMqConnectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
rabbitMqConnectionFactory.setHost("MyHostname");
rabbitMqConnectionFactory.setPort(5672);
rabbitMqConnectionFactory.setUsername("MyUsername");
rabbitMqConnectionFactory.setPassword("MyPassword");
rabbitMqConnectionFactory.setVirtualHost("MyVirtualHost");

Connection physicalSocketConnectionToRabbitMq = rabbitMqConnectionFactory.newConnection();

Channel messageChannel = physicalSocketConnectionToRabbitMq.createChannel();
    
// if the queue already exists, it won't do anything, it just skips the operation
messageChannel.queueDeclare(
    "MyQueueName", //queue
    true, //durable
    false, //exclusive
    false, //autoDelete
    null //arguments
);


DeliverCallback deliverCallback = new DeliverCallback() {
    
    public void handle(String consumerTag, Delivery message) throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println("consumerTag=" + consumerTag);
        System.out.println("exchangeName=" +  message.getEnvelope().getExchange() );
        System.out.println("routingKey=" +  message.getEnvelope().getRoutingKey() );
        System.out.println("deliveryTag=" +  message.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag() );

        byte[] data = message.getBody();
        
        if (data == null) {
            System.err.println("body is null");
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("body is not null: " + data);
            
            try {
                GzipUtil.unzip( new String(data) );
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
            }
        }
        
    }
};

messageChannel.basicConsume(
    "MyQueueName", 
    autoAcknowledge, 
    deliverCallback, 
    new CancelCallback() {
        public void handle(String consumerTag) throws IOException {
            //nothing to do
        }
    }
);
```

If I run this code, the output looks like this:

```
body is not null: [B@5f571234
consumerTag=XXX
exchangeName=XXX
routingKey=tomato_gzip_b64
deliveryTag=1
```

message.getBody() returns some byte array. As I understood, I have to use *new String* to make it a decoded string:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
System.out.println("decodedBytes=" + decodedBytes);
String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
System.out.println("decodedString=" + decodedString);
```

It seems like I missed something, because my GzipUtil returns nothing when I call GzipUtil.unzip( new String(data) );! Does anyone know why?

Comment: Perhaps you should print `new String(data)`.  Also, if you read the documentation for the `close()` methods of BufferedReader, InputStreamReader, and GZIPInputStream, you will see that in each case, the method will close the underlying Reader or InputStream.  Therefore, you don’t need four nested try-with-resources statements.  It is sufficient to write `try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Indeed new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) did the job. Even when it's GZIP or JSON, you have to read the payload as a string. Thumps up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String payload = new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Even if the message content is a JSON file inside a GZIP archive, the payload is still read as a string and with UTF-8 as the default charset. Then the correct content comes out the back and can be processed further.

From this string you can make a JSON file again, which can also be zipped again.

*Good hint from [VGA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) (comment above)!*